# ultra low power adders and multpliers vhdl

Tags: vhdl

am working on a low frequency 30 khz module that need to have an ultra low power consumption. the problem is the research focus on improving the performance of the adders and multiplier and don't focus on the power consumption  .
could some one tell me what are the best architectures for multipliers and adders to have the lowest power consumption nW
thank you

Comment: This is such a localized question that I don' think you are going to get any sort of response here.  SO tends to be more of a coding question site.

Comment: Agreed with Michael. You may have better luck asking this question at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thank you ,let me put my question in an other form what is the adders and multiplier architecture that achieve the lowest power consumption so i can build them using vhdl .knowing that the delay is not an important issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a valid question in the context of VHDL.

Power usage is composed of two factors, static and dynamic. The former is related on the resource area your design uses, and the later is related to the number of transistions per second signals in your design undergo. This dynamic power is due to a number of factors, such as swicthing losses in transistors, and the fact that wires in your design will have a capacative element.

At the very low speeds you're suggesting, static power consumption will dominate, so an approach to take could be on reducing the size of your design.

There are many published designs for bit serial multipliers for instance.

With adders, depending on the width / number of operands, you could focus on using compression tress as a pre processing step.

These are of course only suggestions, and a lot will depend on your target hardware.